# Add attribute to XML with xmltask

Tags: ant, attributes, addition, xmltask

i have this

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

How can i use xmltask to add this attribute?

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" newAttribute="VALUE"/>
```

i cant find anything on the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Its for tomcat user server.xml file, you are trying to add custom attribute?. Per this documention http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html only standard attributes are supported

Answer (score 1):

### build.xml

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" />

<xmltask destbuffer="xml-buffer">
    <fileset file="src.xml"/>
    <attr path="//Connector[@protocol='HTTP/1.1']" attr="newAttribute" value="VALUE"/>
</xmltask>

<xmltask>
    <print buffer="xml-buffer"/>
</xmltask>
```

### Output

```
  [xmltask] { buffer 'xml-buffer' output
  [xmltask] <Connector newAttribute="VALUE" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
  [xmltask] } buffer 'xml-buffer' output
```